# Xcode 9.1 Error when i try installing cocoapods on macOS High Sierra

Tags: cocoapods, macos-high-sierra, xcode9.1

so i typed in:
sudo gem install cocoapods in my terminal and I got the following error, does anyone have an idea why this is happening?  thank you in advance!

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    no implicit conversion of nil into String

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you had to do this instead:

sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods

and that ended up working for me!